# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1

Tags: java, spring-boot

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project

IDEA в Pom файле на строку

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

выдает ошибку

```
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

Файл pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.alex</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-srv</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>demo-srv</url>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить версию плагина в pom.xml которая совпадает с версией spring boot.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```